# Run browse-url in emacs without giving focus to the browser

Tags: firefox, browser, emacs

When openning a link in an Emacs buffer (via the `browse-url` command) each time the command is run the browser takes priority and steals focus from Emacs.

How can I change this behavior? I would like firefox to simply open the link in the background, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using Firefox, it will most likely be the `browse-url-firefox` function which is being called, and you do have some ability to configure default arguments (see the docstring), but I don't see anything obviously useful in `firefox --help`.

It sounds like the `browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground` setting in Firefox controls this behaviour, however. Access that from `about:config` and set it to `true`.

- http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-stop-firefox-stealing-window-focus.htm
- http://labnol.blogspot.co.nz/2006/07/secret-firefox-trick-prevent-browser.html

Comment: This is promising, my Firefox really is loading links in the background now, but it leaves Emacs in this weird state where it has focus but doesn't take any keyboard input.

Comment: FWIW I've just tried this myself (Emacs 24.0.95.1), and I can't replicate that problem.

Comment: My emacs version is slightly newer, but that's probably not the problem. It's probably a windows only issue. I'll test it on my linux at work thursday.

Comment: I tried this out on a Windows XP box, and it seemed inconsistent. Firefox correctly didn't steal the focus, but the first time I browsed a URL Emacs also lost focus. After that first time, it seemed to work as desired (although I only tried it a few more times). I've no idea where the bug lies.